# Updating Multiple values Query In Mysql

Tags: mysql

```
 SELECT id,login,contact_number, store_id, COUNT(contact_number) AS COUNT
   FROM USER 
  WHERE store_id = 1 
    AND is_number_verified = 1
  GROUP BY contact_number 
 HAVING COUNT(contact_number) > 1
```

Now I want to update all the values of number_verified as 0 and want to keep 
     1 row as verified for every user. I tried this but isnt working

```
UPDATE `user` SET is_number_verified = 0
 WHERE id IN
(  
 SELECT id 
   FROM USER where store_id = 1 
    AND is_number_verified = 1
  GROUP BY contact_number 
 HAVING COUNT(contact_number) > 1 
)
```

Comment: First you should learn how to properly use `group by`. You can't group by one column but select another. Best thing is, you activate the sql_mode "only_full_group_by".

Answer (score 0):

You could try with another inner query, like this one:

```
UPDATE `user` SET is_number_verified = 0
WHERE id IN
(SELECT temp.id FROM (      
SELECT id,login,contact_number, store_id, COUNT(contact_number) AS COUNT
FROM USER 
WHERE store_id = 1 AND is_number_verified = 1
GROUP BY contact_number 
HAVING COUNT(contact_number) > 1) AS temp)
```